# array of the package array deletes \hpace at end of cell

Tags: arrays

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ll}
A\hspace{1cm}&A\\
A
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

We have the following result:

[image: Result of the previous code]

Now, if we load the package `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ll}
A\hspace{1cm}&A\\
A
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

The command `\hspace{1cm}` is discarded:

[image: Result of the second code]

Is this a bug of a feature of the package `array`?

Comment: Instead of `A\hspace{1cm}` try `A\hspace*{1cm}`.

Comment: @Zarko : Yes, I know. With `\hspace*{1cm}`, the command is not discarded but I wanted to know whether the difference of behaviour was a feature of not. It doesn't seem to be documented in the documentation of the package `array`.

Comment: A new version of  the `array` package is more consistent than older and `array` use by LaTeX without loading package. BTW, your way of formatting table is quite unusual ... for details of their internals you should address to package author :-) (he read SE).